# How do you avoid subclass call-backs when using Composition?

Tags: oop, inheritance, delegates, event-listener, composition

So I tend to favour composition over inheritance and I would like non-inheritance answers for this question.

There appears to be circumstances when using composition when there is some code in the superclass that requires a call to code in the subclass. This makes for unscaleable inheritance hierarchies which defeats the purpose of using composition in the first place. Here's a demonstration of the problem in C# (although this is a general oop question):

```
public interface IChemistry
{
    void SeparateAtom(Atom atom);
    void BreakBond(Bond bond);
}

public class BaseChemistry : IChemistry
{
    public void SeparateAtom(Atom atom)
    {
        //possible extra logic here
        for(int i=0;i < atom.BondCount;i++)
        {
            //maybe extra logic here etc.
            BreakBond(atom.Bonds[i]);
        }
    }

    public void BreakBond(Bond bond)
    {
        //do some bond breaking logic here
    }
}

public class RealisticChemistry : IChemistry
{
    private BaseChemistry base;

    public RealisticChemistry(BaseChemistry base)
    {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public void SeparateAtom(Atom atom)
    {
        //subclass specific logic here perhaps
        base.SeparateAtom(atom);
    }

    public void BreakBond(Bond bond)
    {
        //more subclass specific logic
        base.BreakBond(bond);
    }
}
```

As you can see with this design there is a glaring problem. When the subclass' `SeparateAtom()` method is called it executes some of it's own logic and then delegates the rest to the base class which will then call the `BreakBond()` method on the base class, not on the subclass.

There are various solutions I can think of for this and almost all of them have pretty substantial setbacks:

- **Copy and paste.** The worst option in this case would be to simply copy the loop (and additional logic) within the base class' `SeparateAtom()` method, to the subclass' one. I don't feel that it is necessary to explain why copy and paste is not the best practice. Another option could be to package some of the extra logic around the loop into extra methods so that it's just the loop that is copied. But the calls to the additional methods are still copied, and breaking things up into multiple methods could break encapsulation. For example what if some of that logic is dependent on the specific context of `SeparateAtom()`and could lead to faulty data if called out-of-context by someone who does not know the code very well?
- **Listen to or observe bond breaking events in base class.** This solution seems problematic to me because the way in which base class functionality should be extended becomes unclear. For example, without prior knowledge if one were to try to extend the class they might intuitively implement the design above and interpret the listener as optional, when it is in fact required if one wants to extend bond breaking behaviour.
- **Make the base class require a delegate.** For example, the base class could require a reference to a `IBondBreakDelegate` which is called inside of `BondBreak()`. This has a similar problem to the listener approach in that the mixture of composition and other approaches makes the intended usage of the base class unclear. Also, even though now there is a delegate which is actually required, thus making the intended usage a little more clear, the base class can now no longer function on its own. Also if one needs to extend the hierarchy with an additional subclass (for example `public class MoreRealistiChemistry` etc.), how would one go about extending the delegated behaviour through composition?
- **Delegate everything instead of composition.** I would prefer not to go down this route because when classes need extra functionality the amount of delegates needed increases (or the amount of methods in the delegates does). Also what if some of the delegated behaviour is optional? Then either there needs to be separate optional delegates for each behaviour that the subclass implements, or you end up with lots of empty method bodies in the subclass.

In general when I commit to a type of design, I would like to do so wholeheartedly. Of course in the real-world there are a ton of caveats. But I feel like this one must be so common that someone might know a good work-around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

(I cannot add a comment because of insufficient reputation, but I want to point out two things.)

First, your code does not compile because the classes do not implement `IChemistry`.

Second, 'favour composition over inheritance' is only a guideline and is not meant to be applied mindlessly. If the model that is under consideration for the solution requires either inheritance or composition, you should choose composition.

For this particular question, inheritance (or rather, specialisation) is the more sensible approach.